# How to keep key store keys secure

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

1. Storing key.jks file in flutter app is secure for flutter app release?
2. Storing storePassword, keyPassword, keyAlias & storeFile path inside the **key.properties** file is secure for app release?

my **key.properties** file:

```
storePassword=<store_password>
keyPassword=<key_password>
keyAlias=<key_alias>
storeFile=<.jks_file_path>
```

Comment: Don't commit these files to the repository, so they will exist only locally. They won't be included in the release build, these are only used to sign the release build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's secure. But don't save these files to public repository

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is secure hovewer there are few things you can do to make it more secure Hovewer it might be less convenient.

Firstly never publish key.properties file and key.jks file. In case you are using git ensure it's included in .gitignore

For anybody to be able to sign an app with this id they need the private key (key.jks) and both the passwords. This might be a problem if your computer gets compromised.

What you could do is storing the key.jks in a password manager app so that in case your computer gets compromised only the 2 passwords are leaked. You do have to get the key out of the password manager every time you build the release and remove it afterwards though